# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use assign-op operators with string offsets

Tags: php

I have a method inside a class to calculate items in a submenu.

On PHP 7.0.12 it works fine, but on version 7.1.12 doesn't works.

Here the method:

```
// Add submenu
            if ( ! empty( $sub ) )
            {
                $entry.= str_repeat( "\t", $level +1 ) . '<ul>' . "\n";
                $entry.= $sub[ 'list' ];
                $entry.= str_repeat( "\t", $level +1 ) . '</ul>' . "\n";
            }
            
            $entry.= str_repeat( "\t", $level ) . '</li>' . "\n";
            
            $count ++;
            
            $output[ 'active' ] = $active;
            $output[ 'list' ].= $entry;
        }
        
        return $output;
```

And here the error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use assign-op operators with string offsets in D:\xampp7\htdocs\SVNwork\...\include\class.menu.php:369 Stack trace: #0
```

That is on the line 369:

```
$output[ 'list' ].= $entry;
```

Does anyone have experience with this problem? Can't figured out.

Comment: What exactly is `$output`? *Probably not an array…*

Comment: try $output['list'] = $output['list'] . $entry  may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838247/fatal-error-cannot-use-assign-op-operators-with-overloaded-objects-nor-string-o

Comment: @daremachine it works like a charm! Thanks man and happy xmas :-)